# difference between やかましい　and そうぞうしい

Tags: words

these two words came up when I was looking at a vocabulary list that I'm supposed to study. I'm having trouble with understanding the difference and the usage of the words. If possible would someone please provide a couple of examples using both of the terms? I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely sure about this, but from the different examples I've seen, `やかましい` seems to be more subjective, based on one's opinion or feelings, whereas `そうぞうしい` seems to be more objective and/or neutral.

Can't type Japanese on the computer I'm using right now, so I'll have to add examples later.

---

#### やかましい

> 隣の人が**やかましくて**よく眠れなかった　→　My neighbours were making such a racket that I couldn't sleep well.
>   **やかましい**社会問題　→　A much-discussed social problem

#### 騒々しい

> **騒々しくて**彼の声が聞こえなかった　→　We could not hear him because of all the noise.

Comment: I read some examples, but I'm still having a hard time with it. I will wait for your examples and see if I can understand!

Comment: Come to think of it「うるさい」も似てるわね…

Comment: I just noticed that when I say stupid jokes my friends often say やかまし(い)わ！(like Kansai comedy), but they never say そうぞうしいわ！They rarely say うるさいわ either probably because it might sound too strong.